# Request re-opening of my question

Tags: discussion

[Do any commentators on scripture take into account the ProtoIndoEuropean root meanings of Sanskrit words?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38288/do-any-commentators-on-scripture-take-into-account-the-protoindoeuropean-root-me)

the question received 2 close votes for being opinion based after which I changed it and the way it is now it is very clearly an objective question for which I have already given an objective answer.

Why is my post being singled out when PIE etymologies of Sanskrit words have been used in the following posts?

2/27/2020 I think those in a position to decide at least owe me a "yes" or "no" answer.

[What are the etymologies of the words brahman (ब्रह्मन्) and brāhmaṇa/brahmin (ब्राह्मण)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10634/what-are-the-etymologies-of-the-words-brahman-%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%a8%e0%a5%8d-and-bra%cc%84hman%cc%a3a-brahmin)

> From the root बृंहति (bṛṃhati), and this from the verbal Proto-Indo-European root *bʰerǵʰ- (“to become high, rise, elevate”).

[Meaning of the " tri " in trishulam - Is it english or sanskrit?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18814/meaning-of-the-tri-in-trishulam-is-it-english-or-sanskrit/18817#18817)

> From Middle English thre, threo, thrie, thri, from Old English þreō, þriē, þrī, from Proto-Germanic *þrīz, from Proto-Indo-European *tréyes.

(the poster disagrees with it - but he did cite the PIE etymology.

[What does the word 'Asura' mean in the Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22128/what-does-the-word-asura-mean-in-the-vedas/36520#36520)

> From Proto-Indo-Aryan * Hásuras, from Proto-Indo-Iranian * Hásuras, from Proto-Indo-European * h₂ń̥suros.
>
> Related to असु (asu-), with several possible etymologies and meanings. In the context of asura conventionally associated with asu- in the sense of "master of the house". This meaning is not further narrowed by its etymology: cf. Avestan ‎ (ahu, “lord”) and ‎ (ahura, “lord”), Hittite  (ḥaššū, “king”), and Latin erus (“lord”). Possibly ultimately from Proto-Indo-European h₂ens- (“to engender, beget”). Compare Old Norse æsir.
>
> The Brahmanas and the Puranas derive asura from another asu-, "breath", a cognate of which is found in Av. ahu-, "life, existence". In yet other post-Vedic Sanskrit literature, asura was back-formed as a-sura, "non-sura", with sura then associated with a group of gods who inhabit Indra's domain.
>
> According to Etymonline,
>
> "spirit, lord," from Indo-Iranian asuras, from suffixed form of PIE root ansu- "spirit"